# Rewrite if statement to switch case with C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I would like to improve my `C#` code by using switch case instead of if statement.
Actually, I have something like that :

```
// Refuse case when validator2 click to send : notator mail + validator 1 copy
if (EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.Refuse))
{
    if (EtapeActuelle.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2))
    {
        documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires, mail.AdressesMailDestinatairesCopies);
    }
}
// Agree case when validor 1 click to send : mail validator 2 + notator copy
else if (EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2))
{
    documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires, mail.AdressesMailDestinatairesCopies);
}
else
{
    documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires);
}
```

In this case, when the first if statement is succeeded, the else statement is called and I don't want that. So I would like to replace by switch case.

But How I can set a switch condition on `.Correspond()` method with `Enumerables` ?

Something like this :

```
switch (EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(...))
{ 
    case ( ?? ):
        break;
    case ( ?? ):
        break;
}
```

Comment: There is no reason why you would want to (or need to) convert this to a `switch` statement (even if you could). I think its just  best to be happy with the declarative code you have and worry about other things... or are you saying `MailTo` gets called twice ?

Comment: Because when the first if statement is ok, a second mail is sent through the else condition. And I need to send only one mail according to the context. With switch case, the `break;` let to leave the switch when one case is ok.

Comment: What is `EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(...)` supposed to do? Returning `true` or `false` depending of the enum?

Comment: Just extract the entire if/elseif/else block into a dedicated method and call return just after you sent the mail, that will shortcut the else.

Comment: Are you saying `MailTo` gets called twice ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes exactly =) 
Sidewinder94 You're right, it could be work like this with return after each MailTo call :)

Comment: @Essex Well, nice thing that I WAS writing an answer on that end

Comment: With the code written above, I cannot see how MailTo would be called twice - if the first if succeeds than code will resume after the else.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing twice the same thing in both `if/else if`

```
if (EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.Refuse))
{
    if (EtapeActuelle.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2))
    {
        documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires, mail.AdressesMailDestinatairesCopies);
    }
}
// Agree case when validor 1 click to send : mail validator 2 + notator copy
else if (EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2))
{
    documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires, mail.AdressesMailDestinatairesCopies);
}
```

You can refactorize your condition such as :

```
if ((EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.Refuse)     // Condition in the if
           && EtapeActuelle.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2)) // <---^
     || EtapeSuivanteAModifier.Statut.Correspond(StatutWorkflowEnumValues.AValider2)) // Condition in the else if
{
    documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires, mail.AdressesMailDestinatairesCopies); // Same action
}
else
{
    documentContainer.MailTo(mail.AdressesMailDestinataires);
}
```